# Clarifications on proof that the fixed points of order $p$, $i_p(G)\equiv -1\pmod{p}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading this paper by Marcel Herzog on jstor: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2040939?seq=1

I want to follow up on a few things about the short proof of Theorem 1, found on the bottom of page 1 of the pdf.

The proof takes $E$ to be a elementary abelian $p$-group of maximal order, how can we be sure one exists?

I understand that each orbit divides the order of $E$, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, so why does $i_p(G)\equiv f\pmod{p}$?

Here $i_p(G)$ is the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$, and $f$ is the number of fixed points on the set of elements of order $p$ when acted on by conjugation by $E$.

Comment: By calling it an "aper", are you accusing Herzog of plagiarism? :-)

Comment: typo corrected.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the paper.  I had been struggling to take the p-group case and prove it for general finite groups. I had Kulakoff and Berkovich and Isaacs for the p-group case, and Berkovich seemed to just assume we knew it worked for all finite groups too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your first question.  Every finite group contains elementary abelian *p*-groups of maximum order since the identity subgroup is an elementary abelian *p*-group, and so Zorn's lemma for finite sets applies.

For your second question, this is just like the class equation for proving a non-identity *p*-group has a non-identity center.  Every orbit has order a power of *p*, so there are two kinds of orbits: those where the power is 0 (the fixed points, orbits of size 1), and those where the power is positive (those orbits whose order is divisible by *p*).  Mod *p*, all orbits of the second type disappear, and so the total number of points, *i*<sub>*p*</sub>(*G*), is equivalent mod *p* to the number of orbits of the first type, *f*.

The paper in question is:

- Herzog, Marcel.
  Counting group elements of order *p* modulo *p*<sup>2</sup>.
  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 66 (1977), no. 2, 247–250.
  MR[466316](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=466316) DOI:[10.2307/2040939](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2040939)